# How do I stop 'print' from outputting to the browser with Google App Engine?

Tags: python, debugging, logging

I'm new to GAE, and have not been able to figure out how to configure 'print' statements to the logging console rather than the browser. For example:

```
class Feed(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        feeditem = Feeditem()
        feeditem.author = self.request.get('from')
        feeditem.content = self.request.get('content')
        feeditem.put()
        notify_friends(feeditem)
        self.redirect('/')

def notify_friends(feeditem):
    """Alerts friends of a new feeditem"""    
    print 'Feeditem = ', feeditem
```

When I do something like the above, the print in notify_friends outputs to the browser and somehow prevents the self.redirect('/') in the post method that called it. Commenting it out corrects the issue.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

EDIT: Google App Engine tag removed as this is general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instead use the `logging` module, like so:

```
import logging
def notify_friends(feeditem):
    """Alerts friends of a new feeditem"""    
    logging.info('Feeditem = %s', feeditem)
```

There are a variety of logging levels you can use, from `debug` to `critical`.  By default, though, the App Engine SDK only shows you log messages at level `info` and above, so that's what I've suggested here.  You can ask it to show you `debug` messages if you want, but you'll probably be overwhelmed with useless (to you) logging information, at least when running in the SDK.

See [the logging module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) for more info.

Oh, and the nice thing about using the `logging` module is that you'll have access to your log messages in production, under the "Logs" section of your app's the App Engine dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

This is not just a problem with GAE.  It is a general issue.  You can't print out HTML and then try to have a redirect header.  The answer to your question is no, you can't change the behavior.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  You might be able to get what you want a different way.

Comment: I'm just trying to use the prints to debug as I go. Is there an alternative that does not prevent the use of a redirect header?

Comment: Use logging as indicated in the other answer